# Dazai Osamu - 人間失格 「自分は[無]{む}だ、[風]{かぜ}だ、[空]{そら}だ」 grammar?

Tags: grammar, meaning

I have a question regarding the following passage:

> 何でもいいから、笑わせておればいいのだ、そうすると、人間たちは、自分が彼[等]{ら}の[所謂]{いわゆる}「生活」の[外]{そと}にいても、あまりそれを気にしないのではないかしら、とにかく、彼等人間たちの[目障]{めざわ}りになってはいけない、自分は無だ、風だ、[空]{そら}だ、というような思いばかりが[募]{つの}り、自分はお[道化]{どうけ/どけ}に[依]{よ}って家族を笑わせ、また、家族よりも、もっと[不可解]{ふかかい}でおそろしい[下男]{げなん}や[下女]{げじょ}にまで、必死のお道化のサーヴィスをしたのです。

(I do not own the book in Japanese, I found the above text [here](http://www.aozora.gr.jp/cards/000035/files/301_14912.html).)

Would it be possible just for the part **自分は無だ、風だ、空だ** to stand on its own as a full-fledged sentence, would it be grammatically correct? Also in the book I own it is translated as "I shall be nothing, the wind, the sky.", which sounds all right to me as a sentence in English, but I am not sure about this bit in Japanese.

Comment: It is a sentence. I'm not sure if it is appropriate to translate 無 as _nothing_. 無 is an extremely important philosophical concept in Taoism.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I guess it's meaning "I'm not anywhere. Even if I'm here, I MUST not make trouble to them as with the air.".
"無" does not exist, "風" and "空" exist always, but people aren't always thinking those.

Comment: In the previous passage, the authour writes "目障りになってはいけない". So maybe he means "I should not stand in the way of anyone, I have to be 'undetectable' (or something)". I must confess that his sensibility is beyond my comprehension.  @Yang Muye: do you really think the authour had Taoism in mind when writing the novel?

Comment: @eltonjohn, I think you are right. (When I read of 無 風 空, I thought of Taoism and Buddhism. But the author was apparently just using them literally. But still, I feel like 無 is something like 空 / 虚 / _void_ or _undetetable_ as you said.)

Answer (score 2):

> 「自分{じぶん}は無{む}だ、風{かぜ}だ、空{そら}だ。」

No, this "phrase" does not stand on its own as a full-fledged sentence or be grammatical by the "textbook" standards.  ***It does not even come close***.

In the context where this phrase was used, however, there is absolutely no problem with it.  The phrase was not created to appear in textbooks or grammar books in the first place; therefore, it should not be judged by their standards.

> 「自分は無だ、風だ、空だ、**というような思い**ばかりが募{つの}り」

As the quotative particle 「と」 tells us, the phrase 『自分は無だ、風だ、空だ』 is only a line that someone said or thought to himself, not to another person.  These lines tend to be more intuitive in nature and often "broken" by textbook standards.

Every Japanese-speaker would know without even thinking that the phrase means the same thing as:

「自分は無であり、風であり、空で（も）ある。」 or

「自分は無で、風で、そして空で（も）ある。」

Comment: <No, this "phrase" does not stand on its own as a full-fledged sentence or be grammatical by the "textbook" standards. It does not even come close.> I don't think so. I don't know about the semantic "effectivity" or artistic merit of the sentence, but syntactically, it is of the form "A is X, Y, Z." There are similar constructions. The most famous one that comes into my mind is  "我は道なり、真理なり、生命なり" = "I am the way, the truth, and the life."

Comment: 「自分は無だ、風だ、空だ」 looks different from 「無であり、風であり、空でもある」 to me. The former looks「自分 ∋ 無 ⇔ 風 ⇔ 空」 and the latter「自分 ∋（無、風、空）」here.